# ¿Cómo sumar 1 al máximo numero de una tabla en SQL y convertirla en texto con ceros a la izquierda?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy tratando de realizar una consulta a una columna de una tabla MySQL, el campo es númerico y debo saber el valor máximo que hay en dicha columna, sumarle 1 y luego devolver ese número con ceros a la izquierda; tengo el sigueinte código pero no hace o que requiero, me trae siempre el primer número.

```
SELECT CONCAT(REPEAT('0', 12-LENGTH((IFNULL(MAX(segd_id), 0) + 1))), segd_id) AS segd_id
FROM fin_seguimientosdet ;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo que comentas se puede conseguir haciendo uso de tres cosas:

- Utilizando la función MAX
- Sumando uno al valor encontrado previamente por la función MAX
- Utilizar al final la función LPAD

Sería algo así:

```
SELECT LPAD(MAX(segd_id) + 1, 6 ,'0') FROM fin_seguimientosdet
```

La única parte que quizás merece ser comentada es la que hace referencia a la función LPAD. Esta función admite 3 parámetros que son como sigue:

> LPAD (valor, longitud_final, valor_de_relleno)

Es decir, la función LPAD lo que hace es recoger un valor, y devolverlo añadiendole tantos "valores_de_relleno" como hagan falta hasta que la longitud final de la cadena sea la que has puesto en "longitud_final".

Osea:

```
LPAD (123, 5, 7)
```

devolverá:

> 77123

Ya que le estás diciendo: "devuelveme el numero 123 añadiendole tantos "7" como sean necesarios hasta que la longitud final sea 5.

En el ejemplo que te he puesto para tu caso, he puesto (sólo como ejemplo) que la longitud final sea "6". De ahí que veas ese 6 en el segundo argumento.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, me sirvio el dato de esa función **LPAD**, no la conocia.

Comment: Sólo apuntar que la `L` de la función indica que la misma sirve para rellenar a la izquierda (`L`eft), pues tiene una hermana llamada [`RPAD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_rpad) que hace lo mismo, pero rellenando a la derecha (`R`ight).

Answer (score 2):

podrías probar de esta manera:

```
SELECT CONCAT(REPEAT('0', 12-LENGTH(CAST((IFNULL(max(segd_id), 0) + 1) AS CHAR))), CAST((IFNULL(max(segd_id), 0) + 1) AS CHAR)) as segd_id
FROM fin_seguimientosdet ;
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos

Comment: Esta solución también me da el resultado que deseo, sin embargo, me inclino mas a utilzar la que sugirio @cooper ya que la veo mas eficiente y de fácil comprensión.